# Popovers in Bootstrap 2.2.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap popover element in my app.

But it doesn't seem to work. When I put the popovers in a div which has the overflow style property set.

However, the same code used to work in the previous bootstrap version.

You can see what I mean in this jsFiddle
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKDY5/3/)

What has gone wrong here??

Here is the relevant code --

HTML -

```
   <body>
       <a href="#"  rel="popover" data-content="test" data-original-title="hello" style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 300px;">This works</a>
   <div id="cartridges">
       <div class="relative">
           <div id="listCartridges">
               <ul>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#"  rel="popover" data-content="test" data-original-title="hello">This doesnt work</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#"  rel="popover" data-content="test" data-original-title="hello">This doesnt work</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#"  rel="popover" data-content="test" data-original-title="hello">This doesnt work</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#"  rel="popover" data-content="test" data-original-title="hello">This doesnt work</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#"  rel="popover" data-content="test" data-original-title="hello">This doesnt work</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                       <a href="#"  rel="popover" data-content="test" data-original-title="hello">This doesnt work</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
                   </body>
```

CSS --

```
@import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css');

body {
    background: #666;
}

#cartridges {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: visible !important;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #AAA;
}

#cartridges > .relative {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#listCartridges {
    width: 100%;
    background: #222;
}

#listCartridges > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#listCartridges > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border: 1px solid #474747;
    overflow: none;
}
```

JS --

```
$("[rel=popover]").popover({
    animation: true,
    trigger: 'click',
    offset: 10,
    placement: 'top',
    delay: {
        show: 500,
        hide: 100
    }
}).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

Comment: Have a look here, I had the same problem. https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5889#issuecomment-10290776

Comment: please answer this query
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724631/bootstrap-popovers-spacing

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from `overflow-x: scroll;overflow-y: hidden;` in your CSS..

It should be

```
#listCartridges > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I know that the problem comes from the overflow. I cannot get rid of that. Those divisions need to have the overflow-x and overflow-y set. What I want to know is that if there is a workaround?