# display bootstrap popovers outside divs with overflow:hidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I've got a question about how to get a bootstrap popover to show above (outside) a slider, which has a wrapper of overflow:hidden, that I can't seem to get around.

I'm using this slider: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/
I'm also using Twitter bootstrap 2.3.2 popovers: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers

both work well together with the exception of the overflow:hidden on the carousel, which is similar to issues like this:
[Popovers in Bootstrap 2.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267272/popovers-in-bootstrap-2-2-1)
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6122

My question specifically is: Has anyone gotten this to work? I've done some moves with height and negative margin to get the vertical height showing, but if the popover is at the edge of my wrapping dive, it will get cut off at the edge.
please let me know if I need to provide any additional detail.

Thanks
Steph

Answer (score 80):

Ok, so I figured this one out.

I changed:

```
$('.popover-with-html').popover({ html : true, });
```

to:

```
$('.popover-with-html').popover({ html : true, container: 'body'});
```

and it's working.

```
container: 'body'
```

was the key, I hope this helps someone.

Thanks

Steph

Comment: I have a simliar issue with bootstrap's dropdowns, however a container option isn't available.

Comment: What do you mean "not available"?

Comment: Thanks Stephanie!  Works with Bootstrap 3.3.3 and Owl Carousel 2 Beta. Solved my problem with Bootstrap Tooltip

Comment: This does not seem to work with Bootstrap 4.0 and Owl Carousel

Answer (score 2):

For other people having this problem in 2021 with newer versions of bootstrap, the solution is using the "boundary" parameter, as "container" doesn't seem to work.

I had to implement a popover inside a sidebar made with [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/dev/AdminLTE/index3.html)

This is what was happening using content:"body"
[image]

And this is how it looks using boundary:"viewport"
[image]

Without this option active the Popper fallbackPlacement takes over and flips the popover direction (the default placement is "right")

As you can see in the [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/) boundary have different options, the default is "scrollParent", but you can use "viewport" like in this case or "window"

Code used in this example:

```
$("#registerPetPopover").popover({
    placement:"right", //Default parameter
    title:"Registra un pet!", //Popover Title
    html:true, //Enable HTML inside popover
    trigger:"manual", //Avoid activating the popover while clicking
    boundary:"viewport", //Allow the popover to go outside its parent
    content:"<div class='text-right'>Clicca qui per registrare il tuo primo pet!<br><a href='#'>Non mostrare più</a><div>"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following in your CSS.
Override overflow property of slider.

```
.carousel-inner{
    overflow:visible;
 }
```

I hope this helps someone.

Got it from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6091

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by overwriting carousel-inner in my own css. Increase height to show the drop down

```
.carousel-inner {height: 350px; width: 100%; min-width: 650px;}
```