# Bootstrap popovers spacing

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas, tooltip, popover

how can we remove extra left spaces on ul li content on popvers
like this

ABCD

ABCD

ABCD

">Top
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.popover .popover-content ul {padding-left: 15px;}
```

Comment: Hi there! While this may be a correct answer, answers typically do better on this site when you provide both a code solution and an explanation that goes along with it :)

Comment: Thanks for the information. will do that. Thanks @MZ